# How to fix OutOfMemoryException when serializing to JSON string?

Tags: c#, json, wcf, out-of-memory, wcf-rest

I have a Class object which contains a property as  byte array in it. This class is a Data Contract to my REST service. The byte array property will take any document whose Max Size is limited to 500MB. When I was trying to consume this service and serializing the object I am getting the Memory Out of exception error. Please find the below image [image]

Below is the code snippet

```
  public static string SerializeJSon<T>(T t)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            DataContractJsonSerializerSettings s = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
            DateTimeFormat dt = new DateTimeFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            s.DateTimeFormat = dt;
            **ds.WriteObject(stream, t);**
            string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            stream.Close();
            return jsonString;
        }
```

Comment: Post your code and exception as a text, not as an image.

Comment: That is what shown in the image.

Comment: @HemantKumar: Pasting the code as text will help people copy it, instead of writing it all to be able to help you.

Comment: How much physical memory is available to you? What is your OS type?

Comment: As a side not, you aren't using the `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings ` object at all

Answer (score 1):

Try "do not use 500mb documents in web service calls". THs is the core problem - you try to use a method call mechanism to transport half a gigabyte of data that likely turns into some gigabyte of in memory objects. This is not what web services are designed to do.

Comment: How could we do this type of scenario applications ?

Comment: WHat application scenario? Bad data design requiring transfer of hugh amounts of data? Hire a competent programmer to come up with a good data design.

Comment: Upload the data somewhere and send a URL of the uploaded data to the REST method. For Instance, Microsoft Azure Blob service or similar.

Comment: Or cut it into smaller parts. I totally fail to see any scenario in which sending 500mb as web service reuqest makes any sense.

Comment: If we knew the reason why he is trying to upload this data we would come up with more concrete advices.

Comment: Sending the data into smaller parts , would this be done at service design level or consuming at the client side ?

Comment: Service level And client side.